# Laptop Brightness not changable

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, intel-graphics, brightness

I have a Lenovo Z500(non-touch), and just installed Windows 10.
looks like I can only change the monitor's brightness when the Lenovo logo shows up after starting up the laptop. If I touch the brightness keys when using windows, my display gets as dim as possible.
I've had this problem before, and after trying a lot of things I found out if I just roll-back the display drivers, the keys will work normally again. But after installing windows 10, it kept me from using my main graphic card which is an Nvidia GT740m.(the other one is an Intel 4000)
so I screw around a little bit and now I think only installing the older version of intel will fix the brightness problem, but still I can't use my Nvidia processor. Also I don't want to roll-back the Nvidia's driver because it's not quite compatible with windows 10 and stuff.
so confused right now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing drivers from NVIDIA ?

**GeForce Windows 10 Driver**

Version: 352.84  WHQL

Release Date: 2015.5.15

Operating System: Windows 10 **64-bit**

Language: English (US)

File Size: 279.2 MB 

[Page Link](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/84891/en-us)

**Supported**
**GeForce 700M Series (Notebooks):**

GeForce GTX 780M, GeForce GTX 770M, GeForce GTX 765M, GeForce GTX 760M, GeForce GT 755M, GeForce GT 750M, GeForce GT 745M, **GeForce GT 740M**, GeForce GT 735M, GeForce GT 730M, GeForce GT 720M